# Port 80 and port 443 open for two IP addresses

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, port

I have Asus RT-AC86U router and IP addresses:

- One IP address is for Home Assistant in a VirtualBox.
- The other IP address is for Nextcloud on Raspberry Pi 4.

I need to open ports 443 and 80 for both addresses.

I already those ports for Home Assistant but I don't know how to open for Nextcloud.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: This kind of question gets asked here very regularly. Question: Are those two IP addresses internal to your local network? If so, you can't forward a single external port to two internal addresses. You need either an extra public IP address (expensive and/or not supported by your ISP) or you need an internal reverse proxy plus two externally registered host names pointing to your external IP. If your application supports it, you could also use different port numbers than 80 and 443.

Comment: @StarCat another option would be to use different ports on the WAN side, but forward them to the correct port and IP on the local network. Usually even a cheap consumer router supports setting a different in and out port for each NAT entry.